# А ну быстро к матери в дом!

Tags: пунктуация

А ну быстро к матери в дом! 
Подскажите, где здесь ставить запятые?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Процитирую [Грамоту](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_785):

> ***А НУ,** междометие*
>
> Выражает призыв, побуждение к действию. Выделяется (или отделяется) запятыми, если произносится без восклицательной интонации. Если междометие имеет повышенную эмоциональность, после него ставится восклицательный знак.

На мой взгляд, Вашу фразу стоит произносить эмоционально, поэтому я бы *не стал ставить запятую после "а ну".*

Answer (score 1):

Наличие запятой зависит от интонации (наличие паузы, расстановка ударения):

1) А нУ, / бЫстро к матери в дом!

2) А ну бЫстро / к матери в дом!